# Make text hidden past container borders

Tags: html, css, sass

I have added text within a square container and I am trying to get the parts of the letters that go past the borders to go away so it only shows whats within the borders. I can not get it to work. I tried overflow hidden and that did not do anything. The `Rw` is the text i need hidden on only the parts of the letters that pass the border

I am using SASS so that is the reason for the variables.

here is the html

```
<div class="container">
<div class="itemsection clearfix">
        <div class="item"><h1>Rw</h1></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
```

and here is the css

```
.item {
        float: left;
        margin: 0 0 70px 6.04%;
        height: $itemsize;
        width: $itemsize;
        background-color: #ddd;
        border: 8px solid #fff;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0px #ddd;
        overflow: hidden;

        h1 {
            font-size: 7em;
            margin: 15px 0 0 -28px;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @OneTrickPony yes they do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work. For some reason compass would not refresh the stylesheet and when It finally did it cut it perfectly